# Reading current upload speed of network adapter returns double the actual speed

Tags: swift, macos, networking

I am developing an app that reads the current network upload and download speeds. The shown values have been working for years.
However, I have noticed that the upload speed is double the actual value.

I have created the following sample that can be pasted into a playground ( the sample has not been optimised for speed and may contain memory leaks):

```
var old: UInt64 = 0
fileprivate func network()
{
    var addresses: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
    guard getifaddrs(&addresses) == 0 else { return }
    guard let firstAddr = addresses else { return }
    
    for ptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next })
    {
        let address = ptr.pointee
        let rawData = address.ifa_data
        
        if let rawData = rawData
        {
            let data: if_data = rawData.load(as: if_data.self)
            let up = data.ifi_obytes
            let name = String(cString: address.ifa_name)
            
            if name == "en1"
            {
                if old == 0
                {
                    old = UInt64(up)
                }
                
                let diff = UInt64(up) - old
                Swift.print(name, Double(diff) / 1024.0 / 1024.0) // MB/s
                
                old = UInt64(up)
            }
        }
    }
    
    freeifaddrs(addresses)
}

for _ in 0 ..< 128
{
    network()
    sleep(1)
}
```

`en1` is my main network adapter. I want the data to be shown as MB/s so I am dividing by 1024 twice.
If I run a network speed test the app shows a upload value of 31 Mb/s which seems to be correct.
However, if I run my playground app during the upload test, a speed of 7.xx MB/s is shown.

If I change the code to show the download speed (`ifi_ibytes` instead of `ifi_obytes`), the app shows a current download speed of 178 Mb/s while my playground output shows 22.xx MB/s which seems to be correct.

Why is the upload speed different? Before dividing the value by two, I would like to understand why this happens.

I have installed a VPN app, which is not active at the moment. I am using macOS Big Sur 11.3.